# How do I change smart-quote language in Gatsby JS?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, gatsby, smart-quotes

I've searched high & low for any documentation on this—without any luck.

I use the Gatsby starter-blog template for my website. My website is in Norwegian and thus should use French *guillemets* (« ») instead of “ and ” as quotation marks.

How do I change the automatic smart-quote behavior? Is it an option in the [`gatsby-remark-smartypants`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-smartypants/) plugin? Is there some sort of library out there that I can use?

I've been able to set the website's language to Norwegian in `seo.js`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your quotes in [inline quotation element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) so the quotation marks are displayed correctly based on the language you set on the `html` element.

Comment: That is a dreary method. I'd like the ability to change the Gatsby automation so that `"` in Markdown becomes `«` or `»`.